# Exporting data from Word tables to Excel using Python

Tags: python, database, excel, ms-word

I have thousands of word documents that have one table on the first page with information that I need outputted into Excel. So far I have this, but I'm not sure why it's not working

```
import win32com.client as win32
import os

myDir = r'C:\Projects\Capital'


XL = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
XL.Visible = 1
XLbook = XL.Workbooks.Open(os.path.join(myDir,'Dealflow.xlsx'))
XLsheet = XLbook.Worksheets(1)
XLrow = 2

for myFile in os.listdir(myDir):
    filepath = os.path.join(myDir,myFile)
    filename = os.path.splitext(myFile)[0]
    ext = os.path.splitext(myFile)[1]
    if ext == '.docx':
        word = win32.Dispatch('Word.Application')
        word.Visible = 1
        word.Documents.Open(filepath)
        doc = word.ActiveDocument
        table = doc.Tables(1)
        XLsheet.Cells(XLrow,1).Value = table.Cell(Row=1, Column=1).Range.Text
        XLsheet.Cells(XLrow,2).Value = table.Cell(Row=2, Column=3).Range.Text
        XLrow = XLrow +1
        doc.Close()
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the code produce an error message?

Comment: It seems to only work for one word document in my folder. Also when I open the excel file the only thing filled out is column: A1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Write tables from Word (.docx) to Excel (.xlsx) using xlsxwriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62043218/write-tables-from-word-docx-to-excel-xlsx-using-xlsxwriter)