# Write tables from Word (.docx) to Excel (.xlsx) using xlsxwriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlsxwriter, python-docx

I am trying to parse a word (.docx) for tables, then copy these tables over to excel using xlsxwriter. 
This is my code:

```
from docx.api import Document
import xlsxwriter

document = Document('/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/Clauses Sample - Copy v1 - for merge.docx')
tables = document.tables

wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/Users/xxx/Documents/xxx/test clause retrieval.xlsx')
Sheet1 = wb.add_worksheet("Compliance")
index_row = 0

print(len(tables))

for table in document.tables:
data = []
keys = None
for i, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    text = (cell.text for cell in row.cells)

    if i == 0:
        keys = tuple(text)
        continue
    row_data = dict(zip(keys, text))
    data.append(row_data)
    #print (data)
    #big_data.append(data)
    Sheet1.write(index_row,0, str(row_data))      
    index_row = index_row + 1

print(row_data)

wb.close()
```

This is my desired output:

[image]

However, here is my actual output:

[image]

I am aware that my current output produces a list of string instead.

Is there anyway that I can get my desired output using xlsxwriter? Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Of course it's possible. Don't write everything on a row to a single cell (`Sheet1.write(index_row,0, str(big_data))`)

Comment: @SiHa hi, thank you for your comment! I tried substituting in your line of code, but it still produces the same output

Comment: Well, yes, my code is your code. I was highlighting the line which is the problem, you are writing all values in a row to the cell with column index 0. You need to change your code so that you increment this value with each `row_data` item

Comment: @SiHa hmm... i get what you mean, but when i run my amended code, I still can't get my desired output. Please see my edited post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the portion of my code update that allowed me to get the output I want:

```
for row in block.rows:
        for x, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            print(cell.text)
            Sheet1.write(index_row, x, cell.text)
        index_row += 1
```

**Output**:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4):

I would go using [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) package, instead of `xlsxwriter`, as follows:

```
from docx.api import Document
import pandas as pd

document = Document("D:/tmp/test.docx")
tables = document.tables
df = pd.DataFrame()

for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        text = [cell.text for cell in row.cells]
        df = df.append([text], ignore_index=True)

df.columns = ["Column1", "Column2"]    
df.to_excel("D:/tmp/test.xlsx")
print df
```

Which outputs the following that is inserted in the excel:

```
>>> 
  Column1 Column2
0   Hello    TEST
1     Est    Ting
2      Gg      ff
```

Comment: Hi Cedric! Thank you for your help! :) i just figured how to do it using xlsxwriter too! I will post my answer